# "He welcome or welcomes you all"

Tags: third-person-singular

For third person we use "s"at the end the word
for example : I sing. You sing. He sings.
same way : 1st person :I welcome you all . 3rd person : **He welcome you all** or should it be **He welcomes you all**

Comment: It follows the pattern; it should be _He welcomes you all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! We use 's' or 'es' at the end of the verbs with third person singular pronouns, such as se/she/it. For example: He does, She hears, It goes etc. So, "He welcomes you all" is grammatically correct.

Comment: In the same way it should be "your organisation welcome you all" - correct?